# Initializing a C#-struct from F#?

Tags: c#, struct, f#, c#-to-f#

I have a simple C# struct that I want to consume from F#:

```
public struct Stat : IEquatable<Stat>
{
    public ulong st_dev;
    public long st_blocks;
}
```

The way I've found to do it feels too C#ish and mutable to me:

```
stbuf <- new Stat()
stbuf.st_blocks <- 0
stbuf.st_dev <- 1
```

Not to mention that in C# I could use the nice `new Stat { st_blocks = 0, st_dev = 1 }` syntax sugar...

Now that I'm getting converted to F#, I'm starting to get allergic to the assignment operator `<-`, so is there any way to improve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's syntax to set properties or mutable fields in the constructor:

```
stbuf <- Stat(st_blocks = 0L, st_dev = 1UL)
```

Note that you don't need the `new` in F# except that it's generally recommended on `IDisposable` things. Also note the suffixes necessary for specifying literals of the appropriate types.